# How to force lower case urls in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm going through our site and converting all our urls to lower case for caching reasons. I will send out an email to all our developers and make it a standard that we use all lower case urls but i know they will end up forgetting and mixed case urls will end up sneaking back into the site. Is there a good way to inspect urls in the response and covert them to lower case?

I will probably do the same on the request side to make sure the url being requested is lower case which i think can be done with url rewriting rules.

Is there going to be much of a perf impact for what i'm proposing?

Comment: I thought URLs were case-insensitive in the first place...

Comment: @David they are but if there is one letter with a case difference then the browser thinks its another item and won't return it from the cache. For Example:
http://example.com/foo.js is cached and you make a request for http://example.com/Foo.js then the browser will make a request (it thinks its a different item) and will not return the item from the browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

How about a 302 permanent redirect in your master page if the path contains an upper case character?

```
if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Any(char.IsUpper))
{
    Response.RedirectPermanent(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" +
        Request.Url.Host +
        (Request.Url.Port != 80 ? ":" + Request.Url.Port.ToString() : string.Empty) +
        Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLowerInvariant() +
        Request.Url.Query);
}
```

Comment: @NitinSawant: you could add to the Master Page or Page's `Pre-Init` event.